# How to correct regex with one substitution, insertion or deletion in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to correct an input string using regex and 1 error distance of substitution, insertion or deletion.

```
My input string is: 1 00.00000000%]
My expected output is: 100.00000000%]

The regex I am using is: (?<![\S])[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?%?(?!\S)
```

As a result of the code I am trying, it does not seem to find 1 00.00000000% as a fuzzy match, instead it finds 1, 00, and .00000000% as 3 separate matches. My approach is as follows:

```
number_format_pattern_map = {
    'us_decimal_and_comma_regex': '(?<![\S])[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?%?(?!\S)' 
}

fuzzy_matched_substrings = []
fuzzy_match_locations = []
fuzzy_changes = []
matched_formats = []

for numbers in number_format_pattern_map:
    number_pattern_string = number_format_pattern_map[numbers]
    substitution = regex.compile('(%s){s<=1}' % number_pattern_string)
    insertion = regex.compile('(%s){i<=1}' % number_pattern_string)
    deletion = regex.compile('(%s){d<=1}' % number_pattern_string)

    substitution_matches = list(substitution.finditer(input_numbers_string))
    insertion_matches = list(insertion.finditer(input_numbers_string))
    deletion_matches = list(deletion.finditer(input_numbers_string))

    fuzzy_matches = substitution_matches
    for match in insertion_matches:
        if match not in fuzzy_matches:
            fuzzy_matches.append(match)
    for match in deletion_matches:
        if match not in fuzzy_matches:
            fuzzy_matches.append(match)

    for fuzzy_match in fuzzy_matches:
        fuzzy_match_substring = fuzzy_match.group()
        fuzzy_match_location = list(fuzzy_match.span())
        fuzzy_change = list(fuzzy_match.fuzzy_changes)
```

Based on my code above, when I print fuzzy_match_substring this should show all the substrings that were matched. At which point i'd pick the most relevant one and do the change (remove a space).

However, when I print fuzzy_match_substring, I do not get the desired substring (1 00.00000000%), instead I get the following:

```
1
1
1
 00
.00000000%
0.00000000%
1
00
.00000000%
```

However, when I remove the square bracket at the end of the string, I get the desired substring.

My question is, how can I find the following fuzzy match 1 00.00000000% with the respective 1 error bound of substitution or insertion at index 1. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your issue. Do you just want to remove the empty space? Can you post a few other examples of input / output combinations?

Comment: that's right.. eventually i want to remove the space but the regex compiler doesn't recognize the correct substring using substitution, insertion or deletion so i can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove empty space in your input that's easy using a simple regex:

```
from re import sub

x = input("Value: ")

x = sub(r"\s", "", x)

print(x)
```

If you write `1 00.00000000%]` it returns `100.00000000%]`.

**Explaining**

Regular expression `\s` matches any whitespace, then we just use `re.sub` to replace the matches with an empty string.

Comment: Hard to believe it's so simple because some kind of fuzzy matching was involved :-)

Comment: Thanks @Telmo Trooper, however the reason I can't do that is because there are other cases where I do want a space between numbers

Comment: Do post a few more examples and maybe I'll be able to help. What is the purpose of your code?

Comment: The purpose is to consume a file with various different numbers/amounts and correct them incase they were incorrectly OCR'd (text extracted). So my goal is to find all matches within 1 error bound of the regex and correct them by removing spaces or in other cases adding a comma or a decimal etc

Comment: Well, we'll need a few examples of strings that would require different treatment. I believe you want to convert the input into a float in Python.